# How to save a record and its model relationships

Tags: ember.js

In a blog application, a user writes a post and selects some tags for it. When the user clicks Publish, it executes the `publishPost` action which currenlty does the following but its obviously not right because, while the post saves, the tags do not. No error is thrown in the console though:

```
actions: {
  publishPost: function() {
    var post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
      title: this.get('title'),
      body:  this.get('body')
    });
    post.set('tags', this.get('newTags')); // array of tag model objects (post hasMany tags in the model file)
    post.save();
  }
}
```

I've also tried just directly adding `tags: this.get('newTags')` to the 'post' object:

```
actions: {
  publishPost: function() {
    var post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
      title: this.get('title'),
      body:  this.get('body'),
      tags:  this.get('newTags')
    });
    post.save();
  }
}
```

How is this usually handled in Ember?

**** UPDATE ****

@Jeff I implemented your suggestion but for some reason it starts a PATCH and executes a SELECT (not an INSERT) statement on the back end (Rails w/ JSONAPI). Any ideas?

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2018-02-26 22:21:43 -0800
Processing by PostsController#create as API_JSON
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"attributes"=>{"title"=>"asdfg", "body"=>"gfdsa", "created-at"=>nil, "updated-at"=>nil}, "type"=>"posts"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `body`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('asdfg', 'gfdsa', '2018-02-27 06:21:43', '2018-02-27 06:21:43')
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 201 Created in 9ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)


Started PATCH "/tags/18" for ::1 at 2018-02-26 22:21:43 -0800
Started PATCH "/tags/53" for ::1 at 2018-02-26 22:21:43 -0800
Processing by TagsController#update as API_JSON
Processing by TagsController#update as API_JSON
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"id"=>"18", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"A.I."}, "type"=>"tags"}, "id"=>"18"}
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"id"=>"53", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"bigfoot"}, "type"=>"tags"}, "id"=>"53"}
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Tag Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id` = 18 ORDER BY `tags`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id` = 53 ORDER BY `tags`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering text template
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)


Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Comment: a patch is fine for JSONApi. But it looks like the tags already existed? Because they have an id already. I can't help any further, because I don't use rails api, neither jsonapi. This article might be a good read: https://emberigniter.com/modern-bridge-ember-and-rails-5-with-json-api/

Comment: You’re right, the issue is I’m trying to create and relate them but all I need to do is relate them (update the join table). You have brought this to my attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the way I'd do it (with RESTApi).
It might not be the best or *the only* solution, it even might be different for JSONApi.

```
publishPost: function() {
  var post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
    title: this.get('title'),
    body:  this.get('body')
  });
  post.save().then(post => {
     let tags = this.get('tags');
     // loop through your tags here
        let newTag = { 
           foo: 'bar', 
           post: post 
        };
        let tag = this.store.createRecord('tag', newTag);
        tag.save();
     // end of loop 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've updated my question after trying your suggestion.